# The multi-part identifier could not be bound. Any solution

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I run the query below, I get error: The multi-part identifier "employee.mail" could not be bound.

```
UPDATE [dbstore].[dbo].[Employee]
SET    employee.mail = empAD.mail
FROM   [dbstore].[dbo].[Employee] AS employee,
       (SELECT employeeID,
               mail
        FROM   OPENROWSET ('ADSDSOObject',
                           'adsdatasource',
                           'select employeeID, mail
from ''LDAP://dc=domain,dc=comp,dc=local'''))AS empAD
WHERE  employee.No COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = empAD.employeeID COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
    OR employee.No COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = Substring (empAD.employeeID, Charindex('-', empAD.employeeID) + 2, Len(empAD.employeeID)) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
```

Any Solution ?

Comment: You don't have mention employee there just update table set mail = will do the job

Answer (score 0):

I guess problem is in the above statement : Try as below

```
UPDATE 
    employee
    SET employee.mail = empAD.mail
```